# jQuery event delegation with .on (this reference)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where does this reference to in a delegated .on event?
Example:

```
$('#foo').on('click', $('.bar'), function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

In the example this will reference to #foo. But how do i access the bar element that got clicked? I might have 5 bar elements and I want to know which one was clicked.

Thanks

Edit:
Sorry i changed #bar to .bar (since it exists multiple times).

The answer that i should just use '.bar' helped. But what if i have selector like this:

```
$('.bar').find('a');
```

How would i incorporate something like this?

This won't work: (cause this will reference to #foo)

```
$('#foo').on('click', $('.bar').find('a'), function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` should be what you're looking for

Comment: You also should not have five elements that match `#bar`, since ids must be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: This particular example is pointless, and in practice you would do much better to put a handler directly on `#bar` instead.

Comment: @Jon Depends. If `#bar` doesn't always exist, and has the potential to be destroyed and then recreated as a new element with that ID during the lifetime of the document, event delegation's probably the better solution.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Sure, that is *possible* (although I think we can agree it's not very likely). That's why I included "in practice", and of course "put a handler on #bar" does not imply "in the exact same spot where this code used to be".

Comment: @Jon What you say makes sense, but the OP specifically asks about delegation, so any answer without it would not be relevant.  It depends on what you work on, obviously, but I use code similar to this very often.

Comment: @Archer: If by "similar to this" you mean simply "delegation" then I use such code very often as well. In any case, IMO the OP does not clearly understand how delegation works and may be using delegation without really knowing why; this is why I am suggesting something not directly considered.

Comment: @Jon I think we're at crossed purposes here.  I'll leave it to the OP to clarify if needed.

Comment: @Archer: Of course. I 'm not trying to convince anyone, and obviously have no vested interest in the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to this...

```
$('#foo').on('click', '.bar', function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Now `this` will be the clicked `.bar`.

If you want a jQuery object then use `$(this)` as normal.

**Edit**

As per the change to question code, you'll need this...

```
$('#foo').on('click', '.bar a'), function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

That simply extends the click event handler to links inside `.bar` elements that may not exist at document.ready.

Comment: Thanks, so no DOM traversing but only selectors :o oh well

Comment: It obviously depends on your goal, but there's *normally* very little reason for further DOM traversal if jQuery is used to it's potential.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways.

1. Use a string selector, not a jQuery object, when calling `.on()`:

   ```
   $('#foo').on('click', '#bar', function() {
       console.log(this); // #bar
   });
   ```
2. Specify a parameter name for the jQuery normalised event object, and use its `target` property:

   ```
   $('#foo').on('click', $('#bar'), function(e) {
       console.log(this); // #foo
       console.log(e.target); // #bar
   });
   ```

EDIT: Ignore the second option. jQuery doesn't accept a jQuery object for the selector, and as a result simply ignores it. You will *not* be setting up event delegation, you'd instead just be setting a static `click` event handler on `#foo`, which works due to event propagation.

Answer (score 0):

An ID should be used once in a page. So you can add a class `fooClass` to your 5 elements and do :

```
$('.fooClass').onclick(function() {
  alert("my bar element: " + $(this));
});
```

and do what you want with `$(this)`.