# How to add click event to dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` list which will be created dynamically with increasing number. I have a `for` loop to bind the click even to all those `UL`.

What i need to do is when user click on it, remove the previously selected list and add the clicked as selected.

Somehow the `k` value in the for loop is not correct for the selection of the increasing list, But it is correct for the click function.

I want to know why it(`k`) is not correct? As it is correctly binded for the click event for all 5 `ul` but not inside the click event.

When i console.log the `k` value it prints `6` for all ul.  I want to know the reason. How to solve this?

**CODE**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    for(var k=1;k<=5;k++){
        jQuery("#sample"+k+" li").click(function(){
            console.log(k);
            jQuery("#sample"+k+" li.selected").removeAttr('class');//removing previous selection
            jQuery(this).addClass('selected');//adding selection for clicked one
        });
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x2qzoeLf/2/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: sorry i don't know about the question already have an answer. Should i delete the question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to bind the value of `k` in a for loop, but problem is when you are clicking the `li` the `for` loop has been finished.

You can bind each value of `k` with a function.

Do something like bellow

```
function addClick(k){
    jQuery("#sample"+k+" li").click(function(){
            console.log(k);
            jQuery("#sample"+k+" li.selected").removeAttr('class');//removing previous selection
            jQuery(this).addClass('selected');//adding selection for clicked one
        });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    for(var k=1;k<=5;k++){
        addClick(k)
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x2qzoeLf/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery event delegation to listen to an event on the parent and pass it to the child. This is the preferred method for capturing dynamically-added elements.

See: [jQuery event delegation with .on (this reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433023/jquery-event-delegation-with-on-this-reference)

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand this delegation to me. Can you explain me Please

Comment: Thanks +1 for your help anyway